# SSRS integration with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I am working on a task where I need to run SSRS and SharePoint on different servers, but right now, SSRS is working in integrated mode. Is it possible to configure a remote SSRS instance in integrated mode with a sharepoint instance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stand under correction, however, I believe you could use the SharePoint SSRS web-part component and as long as the user executing the request (Your service account on SharePoint) has access to the database it should work.

Ensure that the AD user that is running the SharePoint front-end has access to the database (read / execute) - can be added to a group that has access to the database, or

give the user exclusive access to the database <- not the recommended solution

Comment: The webpart, under the hood, accesses report server via report viewer.

Comment: Indeed, however if the calling service account has access to the report server then the report viewer ought to load